# Subscript out of range (Error 9)

Tags: excel, vba

```
SourceBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

SourceSheet = Workbooks(SourceBook).Worksheets(2).Name

If Workbooks(SourceBook).Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("B10") = "SM" Then
    Workbooks(SourceBook).Worksheets(SourceSheet).Range("D11:D3000,K11:K3000,N11:AC3000,CX11:CX3000,DD11:DD3000").Select
    Selection.Copy
```

When I type code above, I am getting result.
But later, when i type code,

```
ElseIf Workbooks(SourceWorkbook).Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("B1") = "Status" Then
    MsgBox ("okay....")
```

It shows `"Subscript out of range (Error 9)".`

Can anybody help?

Comment: A typo :) `SourceWorkbook` vs `SourceBook`

Comment: oOPS Sorry for that.....:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be `SourceBook` and not `SourceWorkbook`

Also this is a very complicated way of doing things. Try this instead.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook '<~~ OR ThisWorkbook?
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(2)     

    If ws.Range("B10").Value = "SM" Then
        ws.Range("D11:D3000,K11:K3000,N11:AC3000,CX11:CX3000,DD11:DD3000").Copy
    ElseIf ws.Range("B1").Value = "Status" Then
        MsgBox ("okay....")
    End If
End Sub
```